Can I replace max function with mathematical expression?
I have a simple function: $f(x) = \max\{0, x\}$. For example $x = ab + cd$. Now we have this expression: $\max\{0, ab + cd\}$, so, can I replace it with mathematical operations like plus, minus, multiplication, division, exponentiation or square-root?

What's the question?  You can write $\max (0,x)$ as $\frac {x+|x|}2$.  Is that what you were looking for?

@lulu
can this be rewritten without an |x|?

Please edit your post to ask a clear, complete question.  As it stands, the rules you want are not clear.

Note that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, so it is equal to $\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2}}{2}$.

I don't understand why you involve both $f$ and the equality or substitution $x=ab+cd$. And what is you want to replace, and why?

Yes, the maximum of $x$ and $0$ can be expressed as
$$
\max(x,0) = \frac{x+|x|}{2}.
$$
From the definition of $|x|$ as
$$
|x| = \begin{cases} x, & x\ge 0\\
-x, & x < 0,
\end{cases}
$$
we see that if $x \ge 0$, this is $\frac{x+|x|}{2} = \frac{x+x}{2} = x$, while if $x < 0$, $\frac{x+|x|}{2} = \frac{x+(-x)}{2} = 0$.

this is what I needed, thank you!

$$\operatorname{max}(x,0)=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2}}{2}$$
(Assuming that $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is taking the positive root of a positive real number.)

Thank you, people here are so smart that they take this question as a joke, or am I stupid?

No, don't say that. You are doing fine. It may just come down to how much time you have already spent on mathematics. All the best!
